# How do i plug my rpi3 into this type of l293d?

Tags: gpio

I bought an l293d from amazon and it came like this with no enable pins or ground for either the rpi or the battery pack for the motor.[image: the l293d that arrived.]

Answer (score 1):

This driver is always enabled type(enable pin is shorted with the instructed line).
So you do not need to enable it particularly. And for activating the motor send signal in thome M(1,2,3,4) marked pins.

Answer (score 0):

The pin marked G between +5v and +12v is the logic and power supply ground.

Not all driver boards support optional enable.  This one does not.

The enable line may be used for motor speed control if driven with a PWM signal.  You will need to use PWM on M1.a, M1.b, M2.a, M2.b if you want motor speed control with this board.